# React Vite 404 error upon deploying on GitHub

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, vite

I deployed a vite react project on git using GitHub pages when i open the project in browser it shows 404 error in main.jsx file. I don't know how it is happened i need a solution for this

Project link

https://sreejith-10.github.io/Food-Recipe-App/

I tried to deploy the project in other platforms but same result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error,
but I was able to resolve it in my repository [my-repo](https://github.com/Ridlo543/IntelliTaskKanban.git)

the steps are as follows,

1. Previously the base in my config was `base: '/REPO/'` according to the documentation but got the error, then I changed vite.config.js to:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: './',
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

However, you can follow the documentation to change the **base to '/REPO/'** or follow the base above

2. then, deploy according to the documentation instructions with github actions [vite.doc](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html)
3. Or you can use the gh-pages package

- `npm install gh-pages --save-dev`
- add script package.json and `npm run deploy`

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
```

- change the branch to (gh-pages) which will be deployed